# Get LiteDB data in Python

Tags: python, litedb

Is there some python wrapper for LiteDB or some way to get data from LiteDB in this language?
I need to parse some information and I don't find anything. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for https://pypi.org/project/litedb/ maybe?

Comment: Have you done any research? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: not so relevant anymore. im curious what you did in the end..

because theres some context in your question thats missing. were you using an existing db or were you in the design stage?
   -  if so why not use a native py nosql embedded db system like tinydb ?

could u migrate the data to it and just go all native for performance?
or is there something about litedb that was important for you to bind your app to it ?

Comment: Try UnQlite. It is not LiteDB but a NoSQL db which can work locally and with Python